# As ISA Practical - Resistors in Parallel

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electrostatics, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Current against the inverse of resistance graph, I = V/R +c](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18148/current-against-the-inverse-of-resistance-graph-i-v-r-c)

How would you set up a circuit with a fixed resistor in parallel with a variable one. We are told to measure the current across the combination resistors and our Voltage is $1V$ and then construct an $I$ against $1/R$ graph what sort of correlation would this be?

Comment: I think the entire point of this exercise is for you to discover the relationship between the current _I_ and the resistance of the variable resistor _R_. It'd be a spoiler to give you the relationship here, wouldn't it?

Comment: We have already done the experiment but the relationship of the graph ws a positive correlation which is were im cnfused about

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that R refers to the variable resistance, the graph should be: $Y=V(x +\frac{1}{r})$ (r is the fixed resistance), which is a positive correlation. Derivation:

Net resistance $R'$ comes from (Resistances in parallel) $$\frac{1}{R'}=\frac{1}{R}+\frac{1}{r}$$. Writing $x$ (coordinate) as $\frac{1}{R}$,$$\frac{1}{R'}=x+\frac{1}{r}$$. Using $I=\frac{V}{R'}$ (Ohm's law),
$$I=\frac{V}{R'}=V(x+\frac{1}{r})$$. Writing I as $y$ (coordinate), $$y=V(x+\frac{1}{r})$$.
This is a linear graph with positive slope $\implies$ positive correlation.

Probably your confusion here was the fact that you were graphing $I$ versus $\frac{1}{R}$ and not $I$ vs $R$ (which is a negative correlation). Taking reciprocals flips the correlation (for positive values).