# How does the equation $1/I = r/E +R/E$ relate to $ y=mx+c$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

I have a graph of $1/$current against resistance, which is a straight line of positive gradient. I know that the gradient represents $1/V$ but I can't work out how the equation $1/I= r/E + R/E$ relates to $y=mx+c$. Could somebody please tell me what each part of $y=mx+c$ represents in relation to $1/I= r/E + R/E$?

Rearranged equation for Emf= IR + Ir

Comment: Where does the expression $1/I= r/E + R/E$ come from? What are the $r$, the $R$ and the $E$? What are on the axis for this - still $1/I$ and $resistance$? And if so, what resistance?

Comment: related to:  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18148/

Answer (score 0):

The $\frac{1}{I}$ term is the analogue of $y$ in the equation for a straight line, $y=mx+b$. I'll guess that $R$ is a variable resistance you control and $r$ is some internal or fixed, possibly unknown, resistance in a circuit. When you plot the controlled resistance $R$ on the horizontal axis, that is the analogue of $x$ in the linear equation pattern.

What this means is that you should get a slope of $1/E$ (if $E$ is constant. If it isn't, this plot is useless) and you have found $E$ if it is unknown. The y-intercept is $r/E$ and you can determine $r$ is it is unknown.

The specific roles of $r$ and $R$ are reversible, but one should be fixed and the other a variable.  If both are variables, then why do the exercise?