# Graph of 1/Current on Y, and R on X axis. What does the intercept represent?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

1/I on the Y axis, and Resistance on X. Gradient represents 1/V. 
Am I right in thinking that the intercept is representative of the Emf of the supply? 
As I believe the equation would be 1/I=R/V+C, so what does C represent?

Comment: The answer your instructors does *not* want is *"the inverse of the current that flows if you put a zero ohm resistor in the circuit"*, but if you think about that it might lead you to where you want to be.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/168252/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169567/2451 and links therein.