# Plotting the Graph of $1/I$ on the Y axis against R What does this represent?

Tags: electricity, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

What does the gradient, the intercepts represent, what is the equation of my line, and how do I use this information to calculate emf?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/168252/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169534/2451 and links therein.